# Вывод 2-ой таблицы исходя из первого id в одном запросе

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю альбомы с картинками.
Нужно вывести отдельно альбом из одной таблицы и в тот же момент вывести одну картинку с id альбома, из таблицы загрузок.

---

**Вывод альбома:**

```
SELECT id,title FROM albom WHERE users = '$users_art_full[id]'
```

**Вывод изображения:**

```
SELECT id,img,view FROM art WHERE albom = 'id альбома из запроса выше'
```

Как сделать это в одном запросе?

Comment: `SELECT id,title FROM albom, art WHERE users = '$users_art_full[id]' and art.albom=albom.id`

Comment: [join](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
albom.id,
albom.title,
art.id,
art.img as id_art,
art.view 
FROM albom 
LEFT JOIN art ON (art.albom = albom.id)
WHERE
albom.users = '$users_art_full[id]'
```

Comment: К примеру у меня 2 картинки из одного альбома, выводит сейчас 2 отдельных альбома а не 2 картинки в ней. Похоже нужно как то сгруппировать их?

Comment: GROUP BY art.albom кажется так, в общем спасибо)